# Satirical book where deformed sociologist advises slacking employees to continue behavior

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a satirical book that was published in the UK before 1983 and written by a British writer.

The book was about people working in small city that had one big employer or factory. Many young employees were late to work or missed their shifts.

The company hired a sociologist to resolve the issue.  This man had a deformed shoulder or a hump on the back and looked like a small and cynical devil. He did not try to resolve the problem. Instead, he advised the employees
to continue their slacking behavior, probably because of job security.

This book represents a period when private companies started to hire sociologists. My search for the book in Google was not successful.